# How to get Tkinter GUI working for serial data

Tags: python, tkinter, serial-port

Im trying to display serial data in a simple gui. The serial data is dynamic (temperature sensor).
This is the code which I wrote for the GUI in tkinter, but its throwing error for line number 9.

```
from time import sleep
import threading
import serial
from tkinter import *
serialdata = []
data = True
class SensorThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        seri_=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
        try:
            i = 0
            while True:
                serialdata.append(seri_.readline())
                i += 1
                sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit()
class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.lbl = Label(self.root, text="")
        self.updateGUI()
        self.readSensor()
    def run(self):
        self.lbl.pack()
        self.lbl.after(1000, self.updateGUI)
        self.root.mainloop()
    def updateGUI(self):
        msg = "Data is True" if data else "Data is False"
        self.lbl["text"] = msg
        self.root.update()
        self.lbl.after(1000, self.updateGUI)
    def readSensor(self):
        self.lbl["text"] = serialdata[-1]
        self.root.update()
        self.root.after(527, self.readSensor)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SensorThread().start()
    Gui().run()
```

While running this code Im getting this error. Can anyone please help resolve it :-

Traceback (most recent call last):
`File "ts.py", line 39, in <module> Gui().run() File "ts.py", line 23, in __init__ self.readSensor() File "ts.py", line 34, in readSensor self.lbl["text"] = serialdata[0] IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: you use the serial module as a variable.

Comment: Ohh. But even removing that isnt working

Comment: It may be that serialdata has not yet been updated and is still empty. Either put in one first element or do a `try except IndexError` for `self.lbl["text"] = serialdata[-1]` in the method `readSensor`.

Comment: You should check whether `serialdata` has data before using it: `if serialdata: self.lbl["text"] = serialdata[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The following example will make is work. Just added a `try` `except IndexError` to make sure `serialdata` is not empty. I replaced the SensorThread with a function that adds a random int between 0 and 100 to the serialdata every one second.

```
import random
from time import sleep
import threading
from tkinter import *

serialdata = []
data = True

class SensorThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            sleep(1)
            serialdata.append(random.randint(0, 100))


class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.lbl = Label(self.root, text="")
        self.updateGUI()
        self.readSensor()

    def run(self):
        self.lbl.pack()
        self.lbl.after(1000, self.updateGUI)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def updateGUI(self):
        msg = "Data is True" if data else "Data is False"
        self.lbl["text"] = msg
        self.root.update()
        self.lbl.after(1000, self.updateGUI)

    def readSensor(self):
        try:
            self.lbl["text"] = serialdata[-1]
        except IndexError:
            pass

        self.root.update()
        self.root.after(527, self.readSensor)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SensorThread().start()
    Gui().run()
```

Comment: Thinking about it a `try except` may be inappropriate for an event that only takes place at the very beginning. Just testing the length of `serialdata` or give the list an initial element ("no value yet" ?) is probably better.